# Images are not vertically centered on footer in li

Tags: css

I'm confused on how I'd go about vertically centering a img inside a li. I tried

```
#footer li {
    height: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

and it didn't work, what am I doing wrong? Here's my jsfiddle on what I'm working on.

http://jsfiddle.net/QsPV2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also define the `img` like this:

```
#footer ul li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It's not the `li` which should be aligned but the ìmg`.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QsPV2/1/)

Comment: Oh, I was just trying #footer li img too, I forgot the ul part. Thanks.